# Display name of a Many2one selection

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

In my module, there is a many2one selection field that refers to the class stock.quant.
 By default, it displays the name of product.

I want to display the location of the product. the _recname defined inside the stock.quant class is **product_id** , i changed the _recname to **location_id** .. But that dosnt change the display name.. What am missing here..

```
class StockQuant(models.Model):

_name = 'stock.quant'
_description = 'Quants'
_rec_name = 'product_id'
```

Comment: How did you change it? Can you share the code please?

Comment: code posted in question

Comment: That's the original code, not yours...